# Start ssh connection and run in the background

Tags: ssh, mac-osx

I've set up port forwarding over ssh so I can securely connect to a web console. Since the bash command is pretty long, I want to create a small script that will do the following;

- Check if there is an open ssh connection to the server in question.
- If it's not open, open it.
- Open browser to the console I want to access.

This is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh -N -l my_username -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_ssh -L <port>:<ip>:<port> <forwarding_ip> > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &

open -a Firefox http://localhost:<port>/url/to/something/secure
```

The ssh connection opens, but the browser can't establish a connection. Is there any way to programmatically open an ssh connection, background it, and ensure it stays open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanted [`autossh`](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/).

> autossh - Automatically restart SSH sessions and tunnels